# Nav is not selectable

Tags: html, css, nav

The nav on the website will not let me click or select. I'm not sure as to why. The pages are all linked correctly. When I inspect the page I am able to click on functioning links. The nav is in between two sections, the header and the about section. There are several elements that belong in each section. Most of which I had to use absolute position to be able to move the elements where I want them to.

```css
#header {
 font-family: "Eras Demi ITC", sans-serif;
 color: white;
 background: rgba(174, 4, 33 );
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 display:inline-block;
}
#header2 {
 font-family: "Eras Demi ITC", sans-serif;
 color: white;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 display:inline-block;
}
#mainHeader h1{
 text-align: left;
 display:inline-block;
}
#mainHeader img{
 width:100%;
}
    
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background-color:black;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
}
.path img{
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 200px);
}
#nav a:link{
 width:50%:
 height:2%;
 text-align:center;
 padding:1%;
 background-color:white;
 display:block;
 height:30px;
 padding:0;
}
#aboutMe img{
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 height:500px;
 object-fit: cover;
}
#path {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 870px);
}
.div1 {
 display:inline-block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px solid white;
 text-align:center;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 color:white;
 position:absolute;
 left:33.5%;
 bottom:-55px;
}
#aboutMe p {
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:rgba(174, 4, 33, .6);
 padding:4px;
 width:40%;
 position:absolute;
 left:55%;
 bottom:-30%;
}
#aboutMe h2 {
 color:white;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 left:30%;
    }
#aboutMe {
 margin:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="path">
 <img src="images/path.png"/>
</div><!--path--> 
<div id="header">
 <div id="mainHeader">
  <img src="images/banner1.jpg" alt="Black Background"/>
  <h1>words</h1>
 </div><!--mainHeadereader-->
</div><!--header-->  

<div id="nav">
 <a href="#aboutMe">About Me</a>
 <a href="index.html#work">Work</a>
 <a href="index.html#contact">Contact</a>
</div><!--nav-->

<div id="aboutMe">
 <div class="aboutImg">
 <img src="images/pic.jpg" alt="Black Background"/>
 <h2>About Me</h2>
    <div class="div1">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
First of all you should use correct tags to mark your question. See here for more details and example tags: [https://stackoverflow.com/tags]
Second thing is that your HTML does not even look wellformed. Please fix this first and provide well formatted code so anyone can read over it fast.

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your in your css `#nav a:link{` with `#nav a{`.
See more details about [styling links](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)